# How to Insert html page table data into database

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a HTML file(Eg-This file contain HTML table). I want to give option for upload this file using wordpress and after upload this file i want to insert file data(Table file) into my database. any idea about this?. I only need html file data insert to database function only.

Comment: get data from dable using `JS`, write `hidden inputs` by this data and after pressing `submit` button send this `data` as `array`. `PHP` should process this data and write it in `db`

Comment: @GugaNemsitsveridze I can't edit the HTML page because it's generated by SAP.

Comment: you can't even write `JS` code?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a DOM Parser in PHP, to parse data from an HTML string.

Comment: @David Yes that's what I need thank you very much